# How to efficiently find Bitwise OR of a range of numbers

Tags: c, algorithm, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-or

Given a range of number [a,b], how to efficiently find Bitwise OR of all numbers in this range. Running a loop for range [a,b] and computing Bitwise OR of all the numbers individually is too much time consuming for a range which is very large, so this is not the option.

Comment: Well, too bad. C has nothing better to offer than a loop. You can try inline assembly if your target arch has appropriate commands.

Comment: Write down the bit pattern for some consecutive numbers. Write down the bitwise or result. Do this for a number of different ranges. Can you spot a pattern?

Comment: If the range includes any 2^n-1 values, that will be all 1, and when you OR it with anything you'll get all 1, so you can skip all the numbers below it.

Comment: So find the highest 2^n-1 value in your range, and start your loop from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing it for all numbers, you can do it for all positions. That would require you only log(n) steps.

So lets try to imagine - when will units place be 1? If either upper or lower is odd or if there is one number between them. So either lower % 2 == 1 or lower != upper.

Great we got units place. Now if remove the lower one bit from both upper and lower bits and repeat we get the other positions.

Only a special case if lower == upper. In that case we return the lower itself.

Following is the code -

```
unsigned int bitwiseor(unsigned int a, unsigned int b){
    if (a==b)
        return a;
    unsigned final = 0;
    unsigned rev = 0;
    while(b){
        final*=2;
        if (a%2==1 || a != b)
            final++;
        a/=2;
        b/=2;
    }
    while(final){
        rev *= 2;
        rev += final % 2;
        final/=2;
    }
    return rev;
}
```

The second loop is to just reserve the bit sequence.

Demo here - https://ideone.com/MCIugW

Thank you @Meixner for the driver code.

Answer (score 4):

Any number of the form 2<sup>n</sup>-1 will be a bit pattern of `n` 1's. When you OR this with any number below it, you get 2<sup>n</sup>-1. So all the numbers below the highest 2<sup>n</sup>-1 in the range can be ignored.

The next number in the range will be a `1` followed by `n` `0`s, and when you OR with this you'll get `n+1` `1`s. Since we selected the above number as the maximum power of 2, we'll never get any more bits in the number.

So there's basically just 2 cases. If the top of the range is 2<sup>n</sup>-1, then the result is a number with `n` `1` bits. Otherwise it's `n+1` 1 bits.

The above assumes that the range includes a 2<sup>n</sup>-1 value. If not, just try the loop (there are probably some optimizations that can be made, but I can't think of them off the top of my head).

Comment: This is correct up until the final paragraph, which doesn't take into account the bottom of the range.  (e.g. the result for [9,10] is 1001 | 1010 = 1011, whereas your approach would say it's 1111)

Comment: @Barmar Incomplete when no 2^n-1 lies in the range.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Yeah, I realized that as I was going to sleep last night.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int dumb(int a, int b)
{
   int z=0;

   while(a<=b) z|=a++;
   return z;
}

int smart(int a, int b)
{
   int d,z;
   if(a>b) return 0;
   d=b-a+1;
   z=0;
   while(d>1) { z=(z<<1)|1; d>>=1; }
   d=z;
   z|=a;
   a+=d;
   while(a<=b) z|=a++;
   return z;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int a,b;
   for(a=0;a<1000;a++) {
      for(b=a;b<1000;b++) {
         int z1=dumb(a,b);
         int z2=smart(a,b);
         if(z1!=z2) {
            printf("fail %d %d\n",a,b);
         }
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```